# How to give timeout into ajax loader?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have problem with added a timer for loader,
I want the loader to take longer to call the function.

I have `$.ajaxSetup` for loaded a loader like this

```
a.ajaxSetup({
headers: {"X-CSRF-TOKEN": a('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")},

beforeSend: function(){
    a('.page-overlay').addClass("loading");
},
complete: function() {
  a('.page-overlay').removeClass("loading");
},
});
```

Then I have calling the `$.ajaxSetup` like this:

```
a(document).on('click', 'a#details_transactions', function(e){
var d = a(this).data('pid'),
    s = a('#CallModal'),
    w = a('.modal-content');
  e.preventDefault(),
    a.post(transaction_details,{_token: csrf_token, pid: d}).done((e) => {
      s.modal('show');console.log(e);w.html(e)
    }).fail((e)=>{s.modal('hide');Toast.fire({icon: 'error',title: 'Something Wrong. Please try again!'})});
 });
```

**If like this, How do I add a timer to make the loader look taking long to load?**

## Edited

I have try using `setTimeout` in between

`s.modal('show');console.log(e);w.html(e)`

Then

```
 setTimeout(function() {
 s.modal('show');console.log(e);w.html(e)
 },2000)
```

But remove loader show after `timeOut`.
I think problem with `.done` because this calling after `.done` function.

So, Should I use `$.ajax` with `success:` for give a `timer` ?

Comment: Can't you add `setTimeout` for both `.removeClass("loading")` and `s.modal('show')`?

Comment: Why don’t you use the timeout attribute of the $.Ajax ?

Comment: @MoshFeu I trying it, but nothing happen with that. I try using `$.ajaxStart` and `$.ajaxStop` but nothing solution also

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff I need a minimal jquery for calling modal, so I use a `$.get` or `$.post`

Comment: Something like that: https://jsbin.com/rehipir/edit?js (It's not working, it's just to show you the code)

Comment: Calling modal? You mean synchronous? That’s never a good idea. You can replace a $.post with a $.Ajax anytime

Comment: @MoshFeu Yes, I trying like that. If I have `setTimeout` in `complete`, I will have trouble with another function running with `$.ajaxSetup` bro. So I think need `setTimeout` in `s.modal('show')` but I search a solution everytime this night

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's the problem with wrapper `s.modal('show')` and `a('.page-overlay').removeClass("loading");`. If you want, you can create a working example using jsfiddle, jsbin etc. so I could get the full picture. You can fake an ajax call using https://mocki.io/fake-json-api. I know it's not an easy task but I don't know how else I can help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have `$.ajaxSetup()` which applies on all ajax request you may have...

But for the below specific request, you want the loader to be delayed.

I think your solution will be to use the `global` parameter in that `$.post()` to avoid `$.ajaxSetup()` to trigger on that one.

> Whether to trigger global Ajax event handlers for this request. <sup>[Ref.](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)</sup>

So you can manage that `.loading` differently here, without affecting the rest.

```
a(document).on('click', 'a#details_transactions', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var d = a(this).data('pid'),
      s = a('#CallModal'),
      w = a('.modal-content');
    
  a('.page-overlay').addClass("loading");  // add the loading class here
  
  // Notice the global: false here!
  a.post({
    url: transaction_details,
    data: {_token: csrf_token, pid: d},
    global: false
  }).done((e) => {
  
    // Use the setTimeout here
    setTimeout(function(){
      s.modal('show');console.log(e);w.html(e);
      a('.page-overlay').removeClass("loading");  // remove the loading class here
    },2000);

  }).fail((e)=>{
    s.modal('hide');
    a('.page-overlay').removeClass("loading");  // remove the loading class here too!
    Toast.fire({icon: 'error',title: 'Something Wrong. Please try again!'})
  });
});
```